# How to find records with an array of _id and potentially other column values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```js
  const query_id = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  const query_type = "A";

  const queries = await Query.find({
    _id: query_id
  }).find({
    query_type: query_type
  });
```

The code above does work. However, it doesn't seem to be the correct way in terms of good practice and elegances.

What is that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.find( { _id: { $in: query_id  } } )
```

**Edit:**

```
.find({ $and: [{query_type: query_type},{ _id: { $in: query_id  }] } )
```

see all queries https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#mongodb-query-op.-and